# How can I use javascript and jquery in a PHP bluemix project?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ibm-cloud

I can't use javascript from index file in my php project in bluemix, neither by external files or `<script></script>`. Is this normal? How can I integrate it to use it properly?

Answer (score 0):

i have use the hub.jazz.net ide and it add to your code some hints to allow jQuery working. It creates a .tern-project file with :

```
{
    "libs": [
        "browser",
        "ecma5",
        "ecma6"
    ],
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "plugins": {},
    "loadEagerly": []
}
```

and

```
/*eslint-env jQuery */
```

before the `$`

Here's my sample app

[link to a sample bluemix with jQuery](https://helloworld-html-f12fd066-a5be-447c-ad15-d2f8ab130566.mybluemix.net/)